# Google Webmaster Tools doesn't like my sitemap

Tags: sitemap, google-webmaster-tools

I am having problems with Google webmaster tools and sitemaps with my domain.

When setting the sitemap all I get from webmaster tool still is -->**Sitemap is HTML** ... and I think I found out the reason:

I registered on google webmaster tools my site as http://mydomain.com but the app is hosted on appspot at http://myapp.appspot.com which is mapped to mydomain.com.

If I register http://myapp.appspot.com **everything works fine** (sitemap validated) - so it looks the problem is somehow related to the fact that http://myapp.appspot.com is mapped to http://mydomain.com.

This it's not ideal because I need a sitemap for mydomain.com ... any idea about how to overcome?

Comment: I think this is not a server related question, quite OT.

Comment: fellas over at SO suggested to post it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure the links in your sitemap are pointing to mydomain.com not myapp.appspot.com.